# How to view a saved matplotlib plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

I have successfully saved my graphs using the `plt.savefig()` function in the `matplotlib` library.

When I try to open my graph using vi, the file is there but there are a lot of strange characters. I guess I'm viewing the code and other info rather than the visualization of the graph.  How do I see the graph in its pictoral form?

Comment: You are seeing serialized data when you use vi to examine the image file. Can you open the image with a browser like Chrome or FireFox?

Comment: I'm not sure. Theres a link in the file near the top but it takes me to the home of a website and not to my graph.

Comment: Actually, I just found another link but it also seems to be commands, not serialized data like my file though.

Comment: Try something like this: `"C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe" KING_LEAR.png`. You will need to change the path to chrome.exe to match the location of Chrome on your computer. You can also use a path to the FireFox executable. Does that make sense?

Comment: What is the name of your image file? Send the full name of the file, with the extension included.

Answer (score 3):

Vi is a text editor, and can't view images as images. The Windows Paint program should be able to view them, however, or on a Mac, Preview should work.

Comment: Well, then, let's say vi is "one of those" text editors that can't view images.